# Running Multiple Versions of PHP Using Apache on Gentoo

Tags: apache-httpd, php, gentoo

I have a Gentoo Linux web server that serves a few PHP-based web applications using Apache. Most of the applications will run on the latest version of PHP (i.e. 7.2); however, one application needs to run on a very old version of PHP (i.e. 5.6). **How can I run multiple versions of PHP simultaneously on the same web server?**

- Gentoo (profile 17).
- Web Server is Apache 2.4.
- Need to run PHP 7.2 and PHP 5.6.
- Apache is currently configured to serve PHP 7.2 via mod_php but PHP 5.6 is also installed.
- Gentoo is configured to use `eselect` to change which version of PHP is used for Apache/mod_php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer is specifically for Gentoo with Profile 17. It will probably work with a few versions plus and minus. I used [Red Hat's PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips/) page for inspiration. The same idea should work for other Linux distributions (of course the specific commands will differ).*

The solution is to use PHP-FPM (FastCGI Process Manager). Each version of PHP gets its own PHP-FPM service that listens on a socket. Apache passes the PHP execution requests to a particular PHP-FPM service depending on which version of PHP is required.

You can use mod_php for one version of PHP and PHP-FPM for the other(s) but I decided to drop mod_php altogether. First, I read somewhere that you can save some memory overhead by disabling mod_php. Second, the solution seemed a little cleaner with all versions of PHP being handled in the same way. Third, it is always better to have the least amount of/only the necessary software installed from a security perspective.

1. **Change your `USE` flags for `dev-lang/php` to add `fpm` and remove `apache2`.**

   Current Gentoo convention is to create a file like `/etc/portage/package.use/php` and specify the `USE` flags here. If you specify exact versions in the file, make sure all versions of PHP you want to use pick up the these `USE` flags.
2. **Install/reinstall the versions of PHP you are going to be using.**

```
# emerge -av =dev-lang/php-7.2.3
# emerge -av =dev-lang/php-5.6.7
```

3. **Change your `APACHE2_MODULES` variable to build the `proxy` and `proxy_fcgi` Apache modules.**

   You specify what Apache modules using by adding/updating the `APACHE2_MODULES` variable in `/etc/portage/make.conf`. Like `USE` flags, Gentoo has some defaults already set-up for your profile. Unlike `USE` flags, it seems that you need to explicitly tell Gentoo to start with the defaults by prepending `$APACHE2_MODULES` to the variable:

```
APACHE2_MODULES="$APACHE2_MODULES proxy proxy_fcgi"
```

4. **Reinstall Apache.**

```
# emerge -av apache
```

5. **Install PHP-FPM.**

```
# emerge -av php-fpm
```

6. **Create PHP-FPM startup scripts for each version of PHP you are using with Apache.**

   The PHP-FPM installation creates a single startup script (`/etc/init.d/php-fpm`) that allows you to to choose the version of PHP to run using `eselect` or by changing the script's file name suffix (e.g. `php-fpm-php5.6`, `php-fpm-php7.2`, etc.). Since we would only want to use `eselect` if we only wanted to use a single version of PHP at a time or if we wanted to use no more than two versions with mod_php for one and PHP-FPM for the second, we will use the suffix method. Instead of copying the script, we want to symlink it (valid suffixes are those directory names from `ls -ld /usr/lib64/php*` e.g. `php5.6`, `php7.2`, etc.):

```
# cd /etc/init.d
# ln -s php-fpm php-fpm-php5.6
# ln -s php-fpm php-fpm-php7.2
```

7. **Change the PHP-FPM configuration so that each PHP version's service runs on a different port.**

   The specific file names vary between versions but you want to edit a config file for each PHP version in these general locations: `/etc/php/fpm-php*/*.conf` so that the `listen` directive has a different port for each.
8. **Configure PHP-FPM services to start.**

```
# rc-update add php-fpm-php5.6 default
# rc-update add php-fpm-php7.2 default
# /etc/init.d/php-fpm-php5.6 start
# /etc/init.d/php-fpm-php7.2 start
```

9. **Edit the Apache start-up configuration to enable proxy modules.**

   Edit `/etc/conf.d/apache2` to add `-D PROXY` and remove `-D PHP` from `APACHE2_OPTS`.
10. **Edit the Apache configuration to tie specific directory locations to specific instances of PHP-FPM.**

    There are many ways to handle this depending on your specific Apache configuration. I decided to edit the `<Directory>` entry associated with my web root so that the default PHP handler was version 7.2 by adding:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9972" # <-- Note port num.
</FilesMatch>
```

With PHP 5.6 used only by exception, I added `<Directory>` directives for each application that needed to use the old version of PHP:

```
<Directory /var/www/oldapp>
    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        Sethandler "proxy:fcgi:/127.0.0.1:9956" # <-- Note diff port num.
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

11. **Add `index.php` as a valid directory index file.**

    In Gentoo `/etc/apache2/modules.d/70_mod_php.conf` includes a directive to add `index.php` as a directory index file in the same way `index.html` usually is. Since we disabled mod_php in Step 9, `70_mod_php.conf` no longer exists to set this up. To fix this, add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to the Apache configuration. Otherwise, if you visit paths like `/oldapp/` you will get a 403 error.
12. **Restart Apache.**

```
# /etc/init.d/apache restart
```

## Other Notes

- If you set-up specific configuration settings in your `php.ini` file (e.g. max POST values, timezone, etc), you will need to set these in all of your `/etc/php/fpm-php*/php.ini` files (for each version).
- PHP-FPM defaults to running as `user=nobody` / `group=nobody`. You may need to change these (in `/etc/php/fpm-php*/php-fpm.conf`) to match whatever your web server is running.
- To handle multiple virtual hosts, perform Steps 10 and 11 for each.

Comment: This was a lot of work for no upvotes. The perils of helping out uncommon distros. :-)

Comment: @MyrddinEmrys: Ha! Yeah. FWIW, the package maintainer mentioned on one of the forums that they added a link to my answer on their wiki. I can't be the only one running Gentoo wanting more than one version of PHP, can I? Well, at least future me will benefit from this when I need to do it again in a few years! LOL

Comment: Gentoo has masked php packages all together and it doesn't look supported anymore, so if you want php with gentoo it directs you to the php website: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php which puts you waist deep in the unix weeds.  Upvote for effort.  Ubuntu 20.04 works fine with php7.4, but those are binaries.